# filtering file from the result of find command

Tags: unix

I want to look for a particular pattern in a directory of files and want to exclude certain patterns while the result is displayed.

I use the following command

```
find . -type f -exec grep -il 'foo' {} \; | find . -not -name "*.jar" -not -name "*.gz" -not -name "*.log" 2>/dev/null
```

when the result is displayed, I see the following error message

```
find: grep terminated by signal 13
```

Can someone please guide me as to why this error message is there and if there is a better command to use for getting the desired result (basically excluding jar files or log files or some other type of files from the result set)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you're trying to use `find` as `grep` in the second half of that pipeline; `find` doesn't work like that. What you should do is have it all in one command:

```
find . -type f -not -name "*.jar" -not -name "*.gz" -not -name "*.log" -exec grep -il 'foo' {} + 2>/dev/null
```

Or

```
find . -type f -not -name "*.jar" -not -name "*.gz" -not -name "*.log" -exec grep -qi 'foo' {} \; -print 2>/dev/null
```

Or let `grep` traverse the tree itself and filter the names after (using `grep`, not `find`):

```
grep -irl foo . | grep -v -e '\.jar$' -e '\.gz$' -e '\.log$'
```

Comment: On macOS these commands don't produce any output. The first one just finishes with no output. The second and third command don't terminate at all. Do I have to use a different syntax?

Comment: @AlexIxeras the first two require a `{}` argument near the end I had missed, edited those in. The third works fine, make sure you include the `.` in the first part.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . | grep -v "jar$" | grep -v "log$" | grep -v "gz$"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
find: grep terminated by signal 13
```

is caused by the fact that find will not accept input from a pipe. Put the `-name` arguments from the second find inside the first. Also using the `-exec` argument to find is almost always the wrong thing to do; it spawns a new process for each grep. This is a good place to use `xargs` instead:

```
find . -type f -not -name "*.jar" -not -name "*.gz" -not -name "*.log" -print0 2> /dev/null | xargs -0 grep -il 'foo' 2> /dev/null
```